# Turn lists inside of a list into different keys and values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this list:

```
[['chocolate', '10225.25', '9025.0', '9505.0', '8750.0'], ['cookie dough', '7901.25', '4267.0', '7056.5', '3550.25'], ['rocky road', '6700.1', '5012.45', '6011.0', '5225.15'], ['strawberry', '9285.15', '8276.1', '8705.0', '7655.1'], ['vanilla', '8580.0', '7201.25', '8900.0', '3500.25']]
```

How can I turn each list inside the list into a dictionary where it would look like this?

```
{'chocolate' : ['10225.25', '9025.0', '9505.0', '8750.0'], 'cookie dough' : ['7901.25', '4267.0', '7056.5', '3550.25'], 'rocky road' : ['6700.1', '5012.45', '6011.0', '5225.15']} ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Let your list be:

```
l=[['chocolate', '10225.25', '9025.0', '9505.0', '8750.0'], ['cookie dough', '7901.25', '4267.0', '7056.5', '3550.25'], ['rocky road', '6700.1', '5012.45', '6011.0', '5225.15'], ['strawberry', '9285.15', '8276.1', '8705.0', '7655.1'], ['vanilla', '8580.0', '7201.25', '8900.0', '3500.25']]
```

You can use a simple comprehension to get the desired result:

```
{x[0]: x[1:] for x in l}

#output
{'chocolate': ['10225.25', '9025.0', '9505.0', '8750.0'],
 'cookie dough': ['7901.25', '4267.0', '7056.5', '3550.25'],
 'rocky road': ['6700.1', '5012.45', '6011.0', '5225.15'],
 'strawberry': ['9285.15', '8276.1', '8705.0', '7655.1'],
 'vanilla': ['8580.0', '7201.25', '8900.0', '3500.25']}
```

OR

```
d={}
for x in l:
    d[x[0]]=x[1:]


#output
    {'chocolate': ['10225.25', '9025.0', '9505.0', '8750.0'],
     'cookie dough': ['7901.25', '4267.0', '7056.5', '3550.25'],
     'rocky road': ['6700.1', '5012.45', '6011.0', '5225.15'],
     'strawberry': ['9285.15', '8276.1', '8705.0', '7655.1'],
     'vanilla': ['8580.0', '7201.25', '8900.0', '3500.25']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginner-friendly solution (specific to this data):

```py
new_dict = {}
for item in lst:
    new_dict[item[0]] = item[1:]
```

Since the string you want to use as a key is always the first item in the list, you can set `item[0]` as key and use the rest of the items in the nested list as the values to that key.

Output:

```
{'chocolate': ['10225.25', '9025.0', '9505.0', '8750.0'], 'cookie dough': ['7901.25', '4267.0', '7056.5', '3550.25'], 'rocky road': ['6700.1', '5012.45', '6011.0', '5225.15'], 'strawberry': ['9285.15', '8276.1', '8705.0', '7655.1'], 'vanilla': ['8580.0', '7201.25', '8900.0', '3500.25']}
```